# How to rollback a specific migration in Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, database-migration, rollback, phinx

I am working on migrations in Cakephp3, I want to rollback a specific migration, I know how to rollback a previous migration by using the follow way:

```
bin/cake migrations rollback
```

But I couldn't find a way to rollback a specific migration.

**Note**: I am using `phinx` plugin for database migrations.

Comment: Vote for https://github.com/cakephp/migrations/issues/173

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally i got the answer,

here we go

```
bin/cake migrations rollback -t <version>
```

Thanks Anyways to SO :)

Comment: Doing it that way, you don't rollback a specific migration, but ALL THE MIGRATIONS UNTIL THAT ONE!

Comment: There's no way, AFAIK, to rollback a specific migration. The only way I've found to "re-run" (careful! to "re-run", not to rollback a specific migration) is to remove its entry in the `phinxlog` table. Edit: and run `migrate` again